# How to load prism in Ghost

Tags: javascript, ghost

I try to load prism.js in my ghost.
I've forked this [repo](https://github.com/dreyacosta/velox) which is not supporting the new ghost 1.x verions. I've updated the tags so I'm able to load the layouts but I'm still unable to load `prism.js`.

In `default.hbs`:

```
{{> loaders/load-prism}}
```

In `partials/loaders/load-prism.js` (here I want to load prism.js and prism.css)

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var l = document.createElement('script'); l.type = 'text/javascript'; l.async = true;
    l.src = '{{asset "lib/prism/prism.js"}}';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.appendChild(l, h);
  }());

  var highlightAll = function() {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  };

  window.addEventListener('load', highlightAll);
</script>
```

And of course I've download my prism.js and prism.css. It's in assets

```
/lib/prism/prism.js and prism.css
```

Comment: Did you also include the CSS file? The code to include the JS looks correct, when you say "unable to load" what do you mean specifically? Is there a 404 in the network console?